# create ear file from myeclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, war, ear

Actually I use MyEclise to develop and deploy a enterprise project(EAR file).

I use Java Build Path to add some other projects and link sources, and added several jar files (as external jar and user library) to my project. (I used J2EE technology and there are some default jar of course )

By myeclise deploying manager I deployed my project on weblogic base_domain and then by weblogic console I deploy it on weblogic.

All is set and there is no problem in all steps.

Now I wanna to create EAR file manually, first I created WAR file which included some jsf files and web-inf directory contains classes, lib directories and some important file like web.xml , facec-config.xml and etc.

In classes folder I have .class files which build correctly from .java files, and on **lib** directory**I copied all jar file from web-inf/lib directory** which created automatically by myeclipse deploying manager on weblogic base domain folder.

I added this War file into EAR file along **APP-INF** directory which contains all jar files **from APP-INF/lib directory** on weblogic base domain folder and META-INF directorywhat contains application.xml file.

When I deploy this ear file on weblogic there is so many error and problems.

Could you tell me what is the correct way to create that EAR file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you have an enterprise project, just export the EAR file. Right click the enterprise project, select Export, then select MyEclipse JEE->Ear File and follow instructions on the wizard (basically, specify a destination for the EAR file, on the file system). This should give you an EAR file that contains the same as what was deployed on Weblogic.

Comment: Hi @Tony Weddle
Thanks for reply, but actually i'm using Jenkins CI tool and with Ant I going to create EAR file, so I couldn't use MyEclipse ! My problem is with libs, I don't know which libs what I used in MyEclipse should I use in EAR and where ? (APP-INF/lib or Web-in/lib)

Comment: You should package whatever libs go into the EAR exported by MyEclipse, or whatver libs get deployed when you deploy directly using MyEclispe. If your app works after deployment via MyEclipse, then it has everything it needs.

Comment: Yes u are right, but what about default jars like JRE system or javaEE libs !! They aren't in MyEclispe deployed folder.
And what about project I added on Project nad link source in JavaBuild Path, what should I do with them and their libs ?!

Comment: You won't need to add JRE or JEE libs to an EAR, as they will be available with the web server (or the system). That's why MyEclipse doesn't deploy them. Dependent projects should be jar'ed and placed in the lib folder, this should be done by MyEclipse deployment, depending on the deployment assembly. So use the deployment layout as a guide.